# How to lazy load init files to speedup Emacs startup?

Tags: init-file, start-up, autoload

My `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file looks like this:

```el
(package-initialize)

(require 'init-my-emacs-settings)
(require 'init-my-emacs-performance)
(require 'init-my-emacs-font)
(require 'init-my-emacs-color-theme)
(require 'init-my-emacs-appearance)

(require 'init-my-tool-calendar)
(require 'init-my-tool-dictionary)
(require 'init-my-tool-clock)
(require 'init-my-tool-speak)

(require 'init-my-prog-programming)
(require 'init-my-prog-license)
(require 'init-my-prog-code)
(require 'init-my-prog-comment)

;;; Programming Languages
(require 'init-my-prog-lang-lisp)
(require 'init-my-prog-lang-emacs-lisp)
(require 'init-my-prog-lang-common-lisp)
(require 'init-my-prog-lang-clojure)
(require 'init-my-prog-lang-ruby)
(require 'init-my-prog-lang-python)
```

I hope to load them **only when needed**. If for init files like
`init-my-emacs-settings` can’t be lazy load. Then I hope lazy load for programming
languages init files like `init-my-prog-lang-lisp`.

Here is my simple idea to load programming language init files only when load major-mode hook.

```el
;;; TODO: convert code into an macro.

(defvar init-my-prog-lang-lisp-loaded nil)
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (unless init-my-prog-lang-lisp-loaded
              (require 'init-my-prog-lang-lisp)
              (setq init-my-prog-lang-lisp-loaded t))
            ))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(defun symbol-concat (symbol string)
  (intern (concat (symbol-name symbol) string)))

;; (type-of (symbol-concat 'ruby-mode-hook "-p"))

(defmacro my-lazy-load-init-file (init-file mode)
  "Lazy load my `INIT-FILE' only when `MODE' loaded."
  (let ((state (symbol-concat init-file "-loaded")))
    ;; state variable
    (defvar state nil)
    ;; load on major-mode hook
    (add-hook (symbol-concat mode "-hook")
              (lambda ()
                (unless state
                  (require init-file)
                  (setq state t)
                  )))
    )
  )
```

My questions:
- how to improve this macro?
- Do you have better solution? If have, please show me. Thanks

Comment: `C-h i g (elisp) Autoload` and also `(elisp) Hooks for Loading`. Using mode hooks is sometimes appropriate, too.

Comment: btw, `require` is very fast and its entire purpose is to load things *only when they are not already loaded*. Wrapping a lisp conditional around a call to `require` is pointless.

Comment: I see, thanks, I will check out those elisp info sections.

Comment: See also http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2286/what-can-i-do-to-speed-up-my-start-up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using John Wiegley's [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) if you really care about startup time that much. `use-package` provides built-in support for lazy/deferred loading.

Better yet, **don't constantly restart your Emacs**. The best way to avoid constantly restarting is to run an [Emacs daemon](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html); then you can create as many frames (both GUI and terminal) as you like that will all start instantly *and*, as an added benefit, share buffers, history, etc. because they're clients.

I use [MJ Wall's scripts](http://mjwall.com/blog/2013/10/04/how-i-use-emacs/) to easily start/stop the Emacs daemon, launch clients, etc. from the command line. I also set `ec` (described in the article) as a startup application so I *never even notice* the Emacs startup time, since it's part of the OS startup.

Comment: I use `use-package`, but don't know `:defer`. I add it now. And I use **Emacs daemon** before, but it has issue that color-theme not applied. Do you have this issue with your solution?

Comment: My theme is applied just fine. Have you tried starting Emacs with the `emacs --debug-init` command to see if there are any errors?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend two things to speedup startup:

- Merge your many init files into a single large file.
- Look at the content of your init files and try to make sure that they don't `require` or `load` but instead, they should just use `setq`, `add-hook`, and `eval-after-load`.